# Валидация поля с помощью JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Есть textarea:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="destinationAddress" name="DestinationAddresses" rows="2"></textarea>
```

В него позволено вводить значения в следующих форматах: `79168859376`, `79168859376, 79163324345`, `79168859376, 79163324345, 79163324345`

Как с помощью JQuery осуществить валидающию, чтобы позволить ввод в данном формате, также осуществить проверку номера, начальное число - 7, остальные десять от 0 до 9?

Comment: Только одно 11-тизначное число или много 11-тизначных чисел через... запятую?

Comment: Может быть много 11-тизначных чисел через запятую, а может быть один номер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вырезать всё разрешённое (числа в допустимом формате, запятые и пробелы) и проверить - осталось ли что-то?
Если да - в форме посторонние символы, выводим ошибку.
Если нет - отлично, значит там было только одобренная Свыше, форма валидна.

Как-то так:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#destinationAddress'),
    check    = document.querySelector('#check'),
    log      = document.querySelector('#log');

check.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let value = textarea.value.replace(/(?:7\d{10}|,(?!,)|\s+)/gi, '');
  
  log.style.color = value !== '' ? 'red' : 'green';
  log.innerHTML = value !== '' ? 'Bad news' : 'Passed!';
});
```

```html
<textarea cols="20" id="destinationAddress" name="DestinationAddresses" rows="2"></textarea><br />
<input type='button' id='check' value='Проверить!' /><br />
<span id='log'></span>
```

Comment: '79168859376, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,79168859376, 79163324345, 79168859376, 79163324345, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,79163324345,,,,' вот такое выражение проходит. Стащу у вас регулярку, попробовать в своём примере.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков, в вопросе не сказано про запятые подряд. Хотя если автору будет нужно, могу легко поправить.

Answer (score 0):

```
text=$('#destinationAddress').val();
arr=text.split(',');
re = /(?:7\d{10}|,|\s+)/gi; //Не силён в регулярках. Надо чуть чуть улучшить под ваш запрос
arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    if (!re.test(item)){
        return false;
    }
});
```